# Excel 2016 conditional formatting based on cell below

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a table with a weekly schedule. Row 2 shows the dates in the week, and row 1 shows the corresponding week day: `=TEXT(B2;"dddd")`, `=TEXT(C2;"dddd")` etc.

I have a rule that highlights the date if it is today, using the "built-in" condition.

I want the cell above (with the week day) to have the same formatting. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Go to conditional format manager and apply the condition to both the cells

Comment: That doesn't work because the top cell is text and not a date.

Comment: I found a workaround. I'll have the top row have the same value as the second row but format it as "dddd", so that the value of the cell is still a date. Then Naresh's suggestion works. I would still like to know the answer to my original question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the image below in explanation of my comment above.. Even if the row 1 is text, if you select both rows in "Applies to" option, it will apply. Note that the column in relative(not fixed by $) in the formula reference.

[image]